# cannot load assembly as ddconfig version=2.0.0.0 is not present

Tags: visual-studio-2015, .net-assembly

I am trying to run my code where a `Servicefactory` initializes all the assemblies. I am getting the following error :

```
Some assemblies could not be loaded. Make sure you don't have invalid binding redirects. If you know there are no breaking changes you can use binding redirects to redirect the following unfound assemblies to the versions you have in  your project.  Assemblies referenced that are unloadable:  Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamSystem.Licensing, Version=14.0.0.0
```

After a little investigation I found that Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamSystem.Licensing references `ddconfig.dll` along with `mscorlib = 2.0.0.0`.

- Firstly, why does it reference an older version of mscorlib(location: `SomePath\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll`), when I have the latest version(loaction : `SomePath\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies`) in my machine.
- Secondly, ddconfig.dll is apparently missing from the location where it searches, but it is again present in the loaction `SomePath\Microsoft VisualStudio14.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies`.

Why is it not searching in the later location ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually do not know why, but I just added the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamSystem.Licensing in my project reference and everything ran just fine.